# How to click an input type using Javascript (not jQuery)

Tags: javascript

Is there an equivalent for the following in vanilla JS?

```
$("input[type='submit']").click();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [`.querySelectorAll()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) in order to select all the `input` elements. Then you could iterate over them and invoke the native HTMLElement [`.click()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click).

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='submit']");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].click();
}
```

Of course you could also just select a single element and invoke `.click()`, but the actual JavaScript equivilent of `$("input[type='submit']").click()` would be to select a collection of elements and invoke `.click()` on each DOM element (since jQuery will internally iterate over each element).